# docker/boot2docker in amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, virtual-machine, boot2docker

I'm trying to run a docker container on an amazon ec2 windows instance (windows 8) and trying to install docker. The only option right now is to install boot2docker. When using a Microsoft access server, boot2docker didn't work because virtual box could not work without hardware virtualization. I thought this may be an issue here but it doesn't seem to be, since the boot2docker-vm is running.

I get an issue when trying to start boot2docker. If I use the Boot2Docker Start.exe I get

```
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start .............ooo
```

And it hangs. If I try to run from powershell with `boot2docker -v up` I get the following:

```
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.7.1
Git commit: 8fdc6f4
2015/08/06 20:35:58 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
.Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022(attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022(attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022(attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022(attempt #0).Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022(attempt #0)...
```

Does this have something to do with not being able to access localhost on an ec2 instance or a virtual machine? If so, how can I work around this?

Comment: You should just boot Linux and run Docker directly, you don't *need* boot2docker. boot2docker is a quick hack that allows you to run Linux containers on an non-Linux OS.

Comment: Ok noted, but in this situation I'm forced to use Windows. I'm attempting to install / pull a container from a windows virtual server which is what my clients will be working from

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest running the container on a Linux instance instead of a Windows instance if you can. That way you can avoid using a VM (boot2docker + virtualbox) in your VM (AWS Windows instance). Then the `docker` CLI can use a native unix socket as well.

Comment: Ok, but what if I _can't_? I'm looking into docker-machine but I don't know if the same problems will arise